# Error using 'use-ajax'

Tags: 7, ajax

I am trying to ajaxify my site. every path should be ajaxified (view-pages, nodes, user-pages, etc)

I simply start with adding the class `use-ajax` to my links.

As a result I get an Error:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /kategorie/studie
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: 
Page title
@import url("http://local/modules/system/system.base.css?nc1ppj");
@import ...
...
```

I figured out that the status of the ajax request is `parsererror` and I found out that this probably has to do with the standart ajax-options:

```
dataType: 'json',
type: 'POST'
```

I assume that the response is not json. But shouldnt be the core standard functionality running out of the box? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Drupal only has HTML versions of those pages defined, if you want (for example) the node page as json, you'll need to implement that yourself, as well as the JavaScript to inject it into the page. Unless I've misunderstood what you mean. But if I haven't, and you're trying to turn Drupal into a SPA, you probably have a lot of work ahead of you I'm afraid

Comment: Just to clear things up a bit further: when you add `use-ajax` as a class to a link, you're asserting that a request to the link's path will return an appropriate response (i.e. commands in a format that Drupal's ajax system understands). You can't just add it to a link whose path returns an html page, it just won't do anything

Comment: you understood me right. does it mean it  is easier to use [ajaxify](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify)? 
otherwise I have to write a callback function for every single link-type? node, taxonomy, users, search etc?

Comment: Easier, definitely...desirable, I'm not sure. One of the benefits of an SPA is not loading the entire rendered markup on each state change. Depending on your theme and markup it might not be as performant as you'd hope. But yes, you'll need node/user/etc paths that render the appropriate markup and wrap it in one of the [AJAX framework commands](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7) for Drupal to make sense of it. There have been efforts (e.g. [Single Page Website](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_website)), but it's an inherently difficult task

Comment: thx. I am gonne take a look. Still, it would be nice if (one day) there will  be an easier solution. So I keep the question opened.